# Load variables from another powershell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have several scripts that could be reusing variables so I'd like to isolate variables in their own Variables.ps1 script, i.e.

```
$var1 = "1"
$var2 = "2"
```

I'm trying to load these variables then print them out in the Main.ps1 script like this:

```
.\Variables.ps1
$var1
$var2
```

This works if I first run .\Variables.ps1 but not if I just run Main.ps1. My environment is PowerShell ISE. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

The variables declared in `Variables.ps1` are at "Script Scope". That is you can not see them outside of the scope of the script that declares them. One way to bring the variables in `Variables.ps1` to the scope of `main.ps1` is to "[dot source](https://ss64.com/ps/source.html)" `Variables.ps1`. This, in effect, runs `Variables.ps1` at the scope of `main.ps1`. To do this, just stick a period and space before your invocation of the script:

```
. .\Variables.ps1
$var1
$var2
```

Comment: totally agree with that solution, in my case i encountered small issue with the path to file, even though all files were in same dir, i had to add absolute path to file as different users had to be able to execute it so it is something like this:    . ./absolute/path/to/file/Variables.ps1

Comment: @T.J. that is why I always use $PSScriptRoot to create an absolute path like this: $PSScriptRoot\Variables.ps1

Answer (score 44):

```
# var.ps1
$Global:var1 = "1"
$Global:var2 = "2"
```

This works. Whether it's better or worse than "dot sourcing" probably depends on your specific requirements.

```
PS > .\var.ps1
PS > $var1
1
PS > $var2
2
PS >
```

Answer (score -1):

Just to ensure correctness ... try this... in main.ps1

```
echo "Test"
. .\Variables.ps1
echo $var1
echo $var2
```

Comment: I'm seeing just the "Test" output.

Comment: Exactly what user "zdan" mentions!