# Powershell Script Will not Run upon Open or Pass Parameter from Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell, scripting, parameter-passing, taskscheduler, windows-task-scheduler

I call the PowerShell application in the Task Scheduler Program/Script prompt as follows:

C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell_ise.exe

I then call the executable script in the Add arguments prompt as follows:

C:\1hwebster\PSISE_Scripts\OpenExcelFile.ps1

This successfully opens my script in a PowerShell window. However, it does not run the script.

I also need to pass a parameter from task scheduler to the script, for which I have tried the -File method:

-File "C:\1hwebster\PSISE_Scripts\OpenExcelFile.ps1" fpathfname 'C:\1hwebster\VBA\DailyEconomicCalendar.xlsm'

This reads the fpathfname parameter as a second file and criticizes my syntax.
[image]

I have also tried the -Command method:

-Command "& C:\1hwebster\PSISE_Scripts\OpenExcelFile.ps1 -fpathfname 'C:\1hwebster\VBA\DailyEconomicCalendar.xlsm'"

This returns an Error processing arguments: There is no option with the following name: Command.
[image]

I have tried all iterations of quotes and single quotes around the -File and -Command contents with no success as well. What do I need to type to successfully run the PowerShell script and pass the parameter from Task Scheduler? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since I simply want to open an Excel file, I bypassed PowerShell and opened the file directly with a scheduled instance of Excel. I would still like to understand how to interact with PowerShell via Task Scheduler if anyone has any insight.

Comment: Best not to use ISE for this. Use powershell.exe

Comment: found weakness. re-wrote answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 10 64-bit. PowerShell 5.1

How to pass arguments from a Windows scheduled task to a PowerShell script.

Create %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\1.ps1 with the following content:

```
Write-Output "
All the arguments are: $args"
Write-Output "    The first argument is: " $args[0]
Write-Output "    The second argument is: " $args[1]
cmd /c pause 
exit
```

Build your scheduled task:

A stopped task will sometimes leave behind an instance of conhost.exe.  If it is not killed the task might fail. Make the following command the first action of your task:

```
taskkill /f /im conhost.exe
```

If there are no spaces and / or quotes in your argument / s you do not have to quote the argument / s.

```
powershell %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\1.ps1 Argument1 Argument2
```

If there are spaces and / or quotes in your argument / s you have to single quote the argument / s.

```
powershell %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\1.ps1 'Argument One' 'Argument Two' 
powershell %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\1.ps1 '"ArgumentOne"' '"ArgumentTwo"'
```

Copy and paste the entire command into a new action in the "Program/script:" box and click OK.  Windows 10 Task Scheduler will ask you if you want to split the paste between "Program/Script" and "Add arguments".  Click Yes.

[image: screenshot paste command into new action]

See [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26734617/8826818)

See [Bing search - pass arguments to powershell script](https://www.bing.com/search?q=pass%20arguments%20to%20powershell%20script)

See [Bing search - windows scheduled task pass arguments to powershell script](https://www.bing.com/search?q=windows%20scheduled%20task%20pass%20arguments%20to%20powershell%20script)