# Dot sourcing a file doesn't work

Tags: powershell

Im following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864128/load-variables-from-another-powershell-script) question but I can't seem to get this working.

(For the sake of testing) I have a powershell module with 2 scripts: variables.ps1 and function.ps1 and a manifest mymodule.psd1 (These files are all in the same directory)

This is the content of variables.ps1:

```
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
```

This is the content of function.ps1

```
. .\variables.ps1
function myfunction
{
    write-host $a
    write-host $b
}
```

When I import the module and call myfunction. This is the output:

```
C:\> Import-Module .\mymodule.psd1
C:\> myfunction
. : The term '.\variables.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\Jake\mymodule\function.ps.ps1:8 char:4
+     . .\variables.ps1
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\variables.ps1:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: `. .\variables.ps1` -> `. "$PSScriptRoot\variables.ps1"`

Comment: What @PetSerAl said. What version of PowerShell are you running?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen It is at least v3 (so `$PSScriptRoot` available for ordinary scripts), because v2 gave slightly different error message.

Comment: My mistake guys, I had a call and forgot to keep an eye on here. Yeah, it's v5.0

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When you use relative paths in scripts, they're relative to the callers `$PWD` - the current directory you're in.

To make it relative to the directory where the current script is located on the file system, you can use the automatic variable `$PSScriptRoot`

```
. (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot variables.ps1)
```

The `$PSScriptRoot` variable is introduced in PowerShell version 3.0, for PowerShell 2.0 you can emulate it with:

```
if(-not (Get-Variable -Name 'PSScriptRoot' -Scope 'Script')) {
    $Script:PSScriptRoot = Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -Parent
}
. (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot variables.ps1)
```