# loading array elements to memory and use them as variables

Tags: powershell

I have the following array (as part of a script) which content looks like that:

```
Arr[0] ->  "$var1 = c:\Temp\aaa"  
Arr[1] ->  "$var2 = c:\Temp\abc"  
Arr[2] ->  "$var3 = c:\Temp\abc\xyz"
```

I'd like to be able to use all array elements in my script.

Is it possible to load array elements to memory and use them in another script as defined variables?
Please note, variables are not part of the script.
I build them into the array and it is stored there.

For example (running on another script):

```
Copy-Item -Path $var1 -Destination $var2
```

Comment: The code from your first snippet is not an array. Do you mean you have a couple variables defined in one script and want to use them in a second script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load variables from another powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864128/load-variables-from-another-powershell-script)

Comment: (?)Those are three separate variables, not an array.

Comment: Those are not variables, this is the content of the first 3 elements in the array.  For example, first element is: "$var1 = c:\Temp\aaa"

Comment: What array? Where does that come from? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: What's the problem understanding?  Arr[0] ->  "$var1 = c:\Temp\aaa"  still not understood???

Comment: Perhaps look into utilizing hashtables?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use single quotes for the entries in your array so that substitution is not used, and also wrap the paths in double quotes. Then you can use `Invoke-Expression` to set the variables from the entries:

```
$Arr = '$var1 = "c:\Temp\aaa"','$var2 = "c:\Temp\abc"','$var3 = "c:\Temp\abc\xyz"'
Invoke-Expression $Arr[0]
```

Example:

```
PS C:\> $Arr = '$var1 = "c:\Temp\aaa"','$var2 = "c:\Temp\abc"','$var3 = "c:\Temp\abc\xyz"'
PS C:\> "var1 = $var1"
var1 = 

PS C:\> Invoke-Expression $Arr[0]

PS C:\> "var1 = $var1"
var1 = c:\Temp\aaa
```

This is truly ugly code, and using a hashtable would be a much more elegant way of doing this.